# Обновление foreign key в hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, foreign-key

При старте приложения hibernate почему-то всегда обновляет внешний ключ.

alter table tbl_archive add constraint FK35qm2sjdv50givwf9krjmkb4u foreign key (device_id) references tbl_device (id)

В поле hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto установлено update.

Если я правильно понимаю, update должен обновлять базу когда в ней что-то изменилось, что оно и делает с таблицами, но зачем каждый раз дергать foreign key. В больших таблицах это занимает много времени.

Подскажите как это исправить? Или это так и должно быть?